# Is there a less naive way to find the (group size) of 2^n MOD prime (>2)?

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I am not sure of the correct mathematical name of the feature I am looking at. Its been a long time since I did math at school.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n seems to concerned with this sort of thing, but leaves me unsure that I have understood what is written.

Below I use '%' as MOD and '^' as 'raised to the power of'.  And am quite wordy.

For all primes > 2, there is a sequence {2^n%prime, for all integer n, 0 to infinity}.
That is { 2^0 % prime = 1, 2^1 % prime = 2, .. 2^(prime-1) % prime = 1, 2^prime % prime = 2, ..}
2^((prime-1) * m)%prime = 1 and 2^(prime * m)%prime = 2 for all integer m.

if the prime is 7 however, the sequence is made up of two instance of a shorter sequence thus:
2^0%7 = 1, 2^1%7 = 2, 2^2%7 = 4, 2^3%7 = 1, 2^4%7 = 2, 2^5%7 = 4, 2^6%7 = 1
and then 2^(6 * n)%7 is still 1; but the are extra values that are also another set of at (2^(3+6*n)%7)

So the cycle-length(prime) is what I have been calling the first n > 0 where 2^n mod prime is 1.

I have inserted some code that calculates this by trial until repetition.. with some trivial uses of it.

```
long cycleLength(long prime)
{
    long remainder = 1 ;
    long length = 0 ;

    do {
        length++ ;
//#define FAST_MODULO
#ifdef FAST_MODULO
        remainder = (remainder+remainder)%prime ;
#else
        remainder += remainder ;
        if (remainder > prime) remainder -= prime ;
#endif
        if (remainder == 1)
            return length ;
    } while (length < prime/2) ;

    return prime-1 ;}

size_t pow_of_2(unsigned n)
{
    size_t result = 1 ;
    size_t pow = 2 ;

    while(n)
    {
        if (n & 1) result *= pow ;
        pow *= pow ;
        n /= 2;
    }
    return result ;
}

#include <iostream>
using std::cout ;

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    long prime = 17 ;

    cout << "cycleLength(17) = " << cycleLength(17) << '\n';

    cout << "2^16 = " << pow_of_2(16) << '\n' ;
    cout << "2^33 = " << pow_of_2(33) << '\n' ;

    cout << "33 % CL(17) = " << 33 % cycleLength(17) 
         << ", 2^(33 % CL(17)) % 17 = " << pow_of_2(33%cycleLength(17)) % 17 << '\n' ;
    cout << "2^33 % 17 = " << pow_of_2(33)%17 << '\n' ;
    cout << std::endl ;
}
```

I have observed that cycles are either length (prime-1) or divisor of (prime-1).

So the run-time is reduced by stopping at (n == prime/2) and returning (prime-1) as that is the only case remaining; and the code is about 25% quicker as a result.

The algorithm is currently O(N) time complexity. I am hoping for clues or insight that might reduce this.

Thanks for reading this.